# MacOS Safari text-shadow missing

Tags: html, css, macos, safari

Here is an example of the problem https://jsfiddle.net/smdLzsx5/1/

Can someone please take a look and see if the bug occurs for them? I am interested in knowing if the problem can be consistently reproduced so I can report it to apple.

Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>

.header01{
    background-color:#d0d0d0;
    overflow:hidden;
    border-radius:5px;
    width:500px;
}

.heading01{
    color:#ffffff;
    text-shadow:0px 2px 4px #000000;
    font-size:40pt;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header01" id="header">
        <div class="heading01">
                BAD<span>GOOD</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In certain circumstances (e.g. the above code) the text-shadow is not rendered - or it appears briefly then disappears again.

I am using MacOX 10.12.6 (16G29), Safari 11.0 (12604.1.38.1.7)

Problem does not occur on Firefox 56 or Chrome 61.0.3163.100

Many things can affect the issue such as:

- Changing the width of the header01 div (change it to 200px and none of
  the text-shadow renders)
- Setting the header01 div to overflow:visible; (shadow renders correctly)
- Changing the heading01 font size to 20pt (shadow renders correctly)

Comment: looks fine on my Safari

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the 'overflow: hidden;' from your '.header01' class. It looks like this is causing it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Laura, but I have noted this in the question. My question is whether the bug occurs for other people.

Comment: I am seeing the issue in Safari